# How to get the hours to display something like this: 9.25 hours from a query in SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

I currently have the following line of code in my query and it doesn't display anything:

```
datediff(mi, Job.DateStart, Job.DateFinished / 60.0,
```

These are the dates and time that I am trying top get the hours from:

Date Start:  2017-01-18 13:52:26.080,
DateFinished: 2017-01-18 13:52:28.163

I am trying to get the hours to display like this:  0.02 hrs.

I have looked and used several codes but none are displaying anything.

Regards,

Comment: the difference between your example times is just 2 minutes. Not 9 hours

Comment: It's 2 seconds difference, why should it show 0.02hrs?

Comment: Nothing at all? When I post and run your code I see _Incorrect syntax near 'mi'_. Ideally you should post a full script that reproduces your issue, post the current output and what you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming `9.25` means `9¼` hours rather than `9h, 25m` (this appears to be borne out by the fact you are dividing by sixty), what you have is very close other than a small syntax issue with the missing parenthesis.

This is evidenced by entering the following into an online tool like the [rextester online SQL compiler](http://rextester.com/l/sql_server_online_compiler):

```
select datediff(mi, '00:00:00.000', '09:15:00.000') / 60.0 as dd
```

The output of that gives you what you seem to be after (albeit with the strange European decimal point):

```
+---+----------+
|   | dd       |
+---+----------+
| 1 | 9,250000 |
+---+----------+
```

To get it as text, you can use conversions:

```
select convert(varchar, convert(decimal(10,2), datediff(mi, '00:00:00.000', '09:15:00.000') / 60.0)) + ' hrs'
```

which gives:

```
9.25 hrs
```

Comment: Thank you paxdiablo. I used the second code (get it as text) and it worked